# Why $(i-1)^{2i}\neq[(i-1)^2]^i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

With real numbers, we have the [Power of Power Law](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws/Power_of_Power):$$a^{xy}=(a^x)^y.$$

However, this doesn't always work with complex numbers. 
For example, [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentLaws.html) states that: $$(i-1)^{2i}\neq[(i-1)^2]^i.$$

I was wondering if there might be an intuitive explanation for why the Power of Power Law (sometimes) breaks down in the complex case.

Comment: This website proves the index laws for complex numbers: https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2014/02/09/the-validity-of-the-index-laws-for-complex-numbers/

Comment: The Power of Power Law is stated for $a\gt0$, not for all reals. The reason for the restriction can be seen in $i=(-1)^{1/2}=(-1)^{2/4}\not=((-1)^2)^{1/4}=1^{1/4}=1$.

Comment: @BarryCipra isn't  $i$ one of the four values of $1^\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: How do you define $$z^w$$ when $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers, not nonnegative real numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Consider how we may prove the Power of Power law for positive reals. First we must define the exponential function
$$\exp x = e^x = 1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3+\cdots$$
And let $\ln x$ be its inverse (this exists because $\exp x$ is **bijective**). Suppose that
$$e^{ab}=(e^a)^b.$$
Then
$$a^{xy} = (e^{\ln a})^{xy} = e^{xy\ln a} = (e^{x\ln a})^y = (a^x)^y$$
as desired. Now, it remains to be shown that $e^{ab}=(e^a)^b$. Call the LHS $f(a,b)$ and the RHS $g(a,b)$ and treat $a$, $b$ like variables. It is easy to verify that their partial derivatives with respect to $a$ are equal, $f_a=g_a$, and similarly for that with respect to $b$, $f_b=g_b$. So these functions at most differ up to a constant, which clearly must be $0$, as $f(0,0)=g(0,0)$. Thus, the conclusion is proven.

This proof, however, breaks down when $a\in\mathbb C$. This is because the complex logarithm is infinitely multivalued, so we cannot do the manipulation we have done above.